# Should Nokogiri::XML.parse be creating separate Text nodes for linefeeds?

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I have an XML document created by an outside tool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite>
  <id>S1</id>
  <name>First Suite</name>
  <description></description>
  <sections>
    <section>
  <name>section 1</name>                    
      <cases>
        <case>
          <id>C1</id>
          <title>Test 1.1</title>
          <type>Other</type>
          <priority>4 - Must Test</priority>
          <estimate></estimate>
          <milestone></milestone> 
          <references></references> 
        </case>                             
        <case>
          <id>C2</id>
          <title>Test 1.2</title>
          <type>Other</type>
          <priority>4 - Must Test</priority>
          <estimate></estimate>
          <milestone></milestone> 
          <references></references> 
        </case>
      </cases>
    </section>
  </sections>
</suite>
```

From irb, I do the following: (Output suppressed until final command)

```
> require('nokogiri')
> doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(open('./test.xml'))
> test_case = doc.search('case').first
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff75851bc44 name="case" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff75851b8fc "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff75851b7bc name="id" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff75851b474 "C1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff75851b1cc "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff75851b078 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff75851ad58 "Test 1.1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff75851aa9c "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff75851a970 name="type" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff75851a6c8 "Other">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff7585191d8 "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff7585190d4 name="priority" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff758518d64 "4 - Must Test">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff758518ad0 "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff7585189a4 name="estimate">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff758518670 "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff758518558 name="milestone">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff7585182b0 "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff758518184 name="references">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff758517ef0 "\n        ">]>
```

This results in a number of children that look like the following:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff758517ef0 "\n        ">
```

I want to iterate through these XML nodes without having to do something like:

```
> real_nodes = test_case.children.reject{|n| n.node_name == 'text' && n.content.strip!.empty?}
```

I couldn't find a parse parameter in the Nokogiri docs to suppress the treating of newlines as separate nodes. Is there a way to do this during the parse instead of after?

Comment: Yes, text nodes between tags are part of the XML specification. But why does this matter? Normally you are looking inside certain elements. Tell us what you want to extract and perhaps we can find a concise way to do it.

Comment: Generally text nodes are ignored until we are on top of the tag containing text of interest. Using CSS or XPath we describe which tag or tags we want, then grab parameters or the desired text node(s).

Comment: I want to instantiate the tree of objects returned by the xml by simply traversing the tree. However, the section subcategory is not required. So a Suite contains both Sections and TestCases. Sections also contain more Sections and TestCases. I just think it would be cleaner without the cruft of the whitespace text elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text nodes are the result of pretty-printing the XML. The spec doesn't require whitespace between tags, and, for efficiency, a huge XML file could be stripped of inter-tag whitespace to save space and reduce transfer time, without sacrificing the data content.

This might show what's happening:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<foo></foo>'
Nokogiri::XML(xml).at('foo').child
=> nil
```

With no whitespace between the tags there's no text node either.

```
xml = '<foo>
</foo>'
Nokogiri::XML(xml).at('foo').child
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcee9436ff0 "\n">
doc.at('foo').child.class
=> Nokogiri::XML::Text
```

With whitespace for pretty-printing, the XML has a text node following the `foo` tag.

Answer (score 6):

Check the [documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions.html). You can just do this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(open('./test.xml')) do |config|
    config.noblanks
end
```

That will load the file without any empty nodes.