# Why am I not able to parse the XML formatted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri, rspec-rails, savon

I am using [teamforge](https://rubygems.org/gems/teamforge) in my Rails app, which works well.

Now I want to test it, so I am using the [savon_spec](https://github.com/savonrb/savon_spec) gem. I am feeding the Soap XML as fixtures.

I am not getting the desired behavior of XML being parsed for the XML that I took directly from the soap UI tool, but when I remove formatting it works like a charm.

I'm not sure why it is not working. Internally, teamforge and savon use Nokogiri.

I will put both XML:

- [XML without formatting works](https://gist.github.com/HarishAtGitHub/7903d536d66bbc9ebc1d)
- [XML that is taken directly from the Soap UI](https://gist.github.com/HarishAtGitHub/4cf1955e60528a7b31a8)

If I remove all spaces and turn it into a single line it works as expected.

I was initially struggling to find why the XML was not working then I was able to narrow down to the point that if I put the unformatted XML it works.

Why does the Soap UI format XML break the parsing?

1. I just wanted to see what actually breaks so I started introducing indentation one step at a time. This is the format that finally works - [xml](https://gist.github.com/HarishAtGitHub/1a1792425e6729e30459).
2. Then the next format with next line indented breaks. This is the broken one - [breakingformatxml](https://gist.github.com/HarishAtGitHub/3eae5afe38dbf72d8858)

Comment: Where is the parsing failing? On the TeamForge side? If so, it sounds like they're parsing badly. Is the issue on the teamforge gem side? If so, it sounds like they're parsing badly.

Comment: Ya I am just looking at that part . I have updated the my further debugging results

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason .

The answer is that the nokogiri xpath [nokogiri-1.6.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.6.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb#L145-161) returns a NodeSet which has array of nodes . This while creating array it respects each newline and considers it to be a valid node and sets it as TextNode . so what happened was that the teamforge ruby gem did not expect or handle this case of a possible new line in xml so the parsing of xml and converting to object broke as there is no such attribute as text in the object .

some like me has also faced a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612719/should-nokogirixml-parse-be-creating-separate-text-nodes-for-linefeeds)